# First angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I've just written my first angularjs directive, and I was hoping to get some feedback. I already have two doubts myself.

- Why is it that I must use `tElement.append()` to append the canvas element? `tElement.html()` doesn't work, at all. That just returns `[[object HTMLCanvasElement]]` in plain text inside of the element.
- Should I be accessing `canvasElement[0]`? It feels wrong, but it might not be.

Here's the code:

```js
angular.module('yupDraw', [])
    .directive('yupCanvas', function factory() {

        // Create elements (templates) in vars here
        var canvasTemplate = '<canvas></canvas>';

        return {

            restrict: 'E',
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {

                var canvasElement = angular.element(canvasTemplate);

                tElement.append(canvasElement);

                return function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasElement[0], {
                        isDrawingMode: true
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

And I'm simply calling the directive like so: `<yup-canvas></yup-canvas>`

Fire away! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular includes a tiny subset of jQuery called `jqLite` which is what you get with `angular.element`.  The `html()` [method](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/jqLite.js#L523) on it specifically only accepts a string, not an array of jqLite objects like jQuery normally does I think (unless it's a bug).

One solution would be to use jquery.  If you include jquery before angular, angular will use your jquery instead of the embedded jqlite.  Swap the script tags in [***this fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/uCwCd/) to see it toggle between working and not.

Another solution would be to use the outerHTML of your canvas element's html node like in [***this fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/JBnXP/):

```
tElement.html(canvasElement[0].outerHTML);
```

I think using canvasElement[0] is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I never used `compile:` so I am not sure what you use it for but.. I think there is a template property in directives and you can easily access the canvas with `.children[0]`

```
app.directive('yupCanvas', function factory() {

    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<canvas></canvas>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(element.children[0], {
            isDrawingMode: true
          });

        }
    };
});
```

Maybe I am not understanding what you are trying to do though...